# MySQL to MS ACCESS 2007?

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-access

How can i export from MySQL to MS ACCESS 2007 in c#? Any tutorials?

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Comment: you mean mysql -> csv -> ms access? i was kind of thinking of this too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NHibernate with 2 session factories, load entities from MySQL and persist them to MS Access. 
This would help if you will change databases in the future. 
Also respects referential integrity

Answer (score 1):

In Access, go to File => get external data, Import, then choose ODBC as your source. You have to have the MySQL ODBC drivers installed first, and in the process you may have to set up a DSN. Once you've connected, you'll see a list of tables and then you can import them. Whether or not this will get the data types correct is an open question.

If this is something you need to do often, then you should set up an empty shell Access database and then import the data with INSERT queries that specify the ODBC connect string to the MySQL database in the FROM clause.